# android sqlite have gap after delete row?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have 4 EditTexts in dataBase

I delete the second one

The database is numbered 1,3,4

I now want it to be renumbered as 1,2,3.

I looked at many solutions
But I could not find a complete answer..
I do not know what should be in writing
I tried the following code .
But it did not happen

```
db.delete("SQLITE_SEQUENCE","NAME = ?",new String[]{TABLE_NAME});
```

Does anyone have the full answer ?

Comment: If I understood what you are asking... **NO**, the ids are not renumbered. Which would be really dangerous when different tables are connected by an id.

Answer (score 1):

In general, this is poor design for a database. An ID should be consistent for a piece of data, regardless of its peers--it should not fluctuate just because another row was deleted.

That being said, you could always use an `UPDATE` statement to `SET ID = ID-1 WHERE ID > (the ID of the row you deleted)`. This would work. I don't recommend this approach, but you can.

Comment: dataBase.execSQL("UPDATE T1 SET ID=ID-1  WHERE ID>"+rowDelete+";");I understood correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

You can recover this space by executing the SQLite [VACUUM](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) command.

Call `db.execSQL("VACUUM")` after delete

Comment: This is not what was asked for.

Comment: @CL. take a look at this example: http://www.sqlabs.com/blog/2010/12/sqlite-and-unique-rowid-something-you-really-need-to-know/ is not that what was asked for?

Comment: That applies only to an implicit `rowid` column; an explicit INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column never gets changed by [VACUUM](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html).